# dequeueing function working with 2 queues encounters segfault?

Tags: c, struct, queue, dynamic-memory-allocation, singly-linked-list

The function below is supposed to dequeue a structure that is made of 2 queues. Each time we dequeue the first queue, its rear needs to become the front of the second queue. Essentially moving the first element in the second queue to the first queue to be its rear. I came up with the algorithm below:

```
int dequeue(queue* Q1,queue* Q2){

    node* temp;

    if(Q1->rear=NULL){
        return 0;
    }

    if(count<3){
        temp=Q1->front;
        Q1->front=Q1->front->next;
        free(temp);
        count--;
        return 1;
    }

    if(count>=3){

        temp=Q1->front;
        Q1->front=Q1->front->next;
        free(temp);

        Q1->rear->next=Q2->front;
        Q1->rear=Q1->rear->next;
        Q2->front=Q2->front->next;
        Q1->rear->next=NULL;

        if(Q2->front=NULL){
            Q2->rear=NULL;
        }

        count--;
        return 1;

    }
}
```

It gives a segfault at `Q1->rear->next=Q2->front;`

is there an alternative way to achieve this?

Comment: For me this condition if(count<3){ does not make a sense.

Comment: Also there is a typo         if(Q2->front=NULL){
            Q2->rear=NULL;
        } You are using assignment instead of comparison

Comment: It is unclear whether variable count means the total number of nodes in the both queue or not.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow it's a global variable that refers to the total number of nodes in both queues

Comment: It is a bad approach when a function depends on a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

For starters there is a typo in the condition of the if statement

```
    if(Q2->front=NULL){
        Q2->rear=NULL;
    }
```

You are using assignment instead of comparison.

There is also a bug in this if statement

```
if(count<3){
    temp=Q1->front;
    Q1->front=Q1->front->next;
    free(temp);
    count--;
    return 1;
}
```

`q1-front` after this statement

```
    Q1->front=Q1->front->next;
```

can be equal to `NULL`. In this case you need to set also `Q1->rare` to `NULL`.

But in any case your approach with the if statements

```
if(count<3){
    temp=Q1->front;
    Q1->front=Q1->front->next;
    free(temp);
    count--;
    return 1;
}

if(count>=3){

    temp=Q1->front;
    Q1->front=Q1->front->next;
    free(temp);
    //...
```

makes the code less clear and as it occurred error prone.

I would write the function the following way

```
int dequeue( queue *q1, queue *q2 )
{
    int success = q1->front != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        if ( q2->front != NULL )
        {
            q1->rear->next = q2->front;
            q1->rear = q1->rear->next;  

            q2->front = q2->front->next;

            if ( q2->front == NULL ) q2->rear = NULL;

            q1->rear->next = NULL;
        }

        node *tmp = q1->front;

        q1->front = q1->front->next;
        if ( q1->front == NULL ) q1->rear = NULL;

        free( tmp );

        --count;
    }

    return success;
}
```

Pay attention to that it is a bad programming practice when a function depends on a global variable (I mean the variable `count`). You could avoid such a situation wrapping queues and the variable `count` in a structure.

Here is a demonstration program that shows the function in action.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
} node;

typedef struct queue
{
    node *front;
    node *rear;
} queue;

size_t count;

int dequeue( queue *q1, queue *q2 )
{
    int success = q1->front != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        if ( q2->front != NULL )
        {
            q1->rear->next = q2->front;
            q1->rear = q1->rear->next;  

            q2->front = q2->front->next;

            if ( q2->front == NULL ) q2->rear = NULL;

            q1->rear->next = NULL;
        }

        node *tmp = q1->front;

        q1->front = q1->front->next;
        if ( q1->front == NULL ) q1->rear = NULL;

        free( tmp );

        --count;
    }

    return success;
}

int push( queue *q, int data )
{
    node *new_node = malloc( sizeof( node ) );
    int success = new_node != NULL;
    
    if ( success )
    {
        new_node->data = data;
        new_node->next = NULL;
        
        if ( q->rear == NULL )
        {
            q->front = new_node;
        }
        else
        {
            q->rear->next = new_node;
        }
        
        q->rear = new_node;
        
        ++count;
    }
    
    return success;
}

int empty( const queue *q )
{
    return q->front == NULL;
}

int front( queue *q )
{
    return q->front->data;
}

int main( void )
{
    queue q1 = { .front = NULL, .rear = NULL };  
    queue q2 = { .front = NULL, .rear = NULL };  
    
    const int N = 10;
    
    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        if ( i < N / 2 ) push( &q1, i );
        else push( &q2, i );
    }
    
    while ( !empty( &q1 ) )
    {
        printf( "%d ", front( &q1 ) );
        dequeue( &q1, &q2 );
    }
    
    putchar( '\n' );

    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        if ( i < N / 2 ) push( &q1, i );
        else push( &q2, i );
    }
    
    while ( !empty( &q1 ) )
    {
        printf( "%d ", front( &q1 ) );
        dequeue( &q1, &q2 );
    }
    
    putchar( '\n' );
}
```

The program output is

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

There are the same code is executed two times to show that the function `dequeue` works correctly.